# SQL Server Case statement does not work in Delphi TADODataSet

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

In Delphi XE5, I use a `TADODataSet` and set it's `CommandText` to this command **(with `CASE`)**:

```sql
SELECT 
    Master.*,
    CASE
       ( SELECT TOP (1) personeli_State 
         FROM Detail 
         WHERE Detail.FK_Key = Master.pk_key 
           AND Detail.personeli_State = 'Test' 
           AND Detail.sended = 0 ) 
       WHEN 'Test' THEN 'Test exist'
       ELSE '' 
     END AS PersonState
FROM   
    Master
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ExtraInfo ON ExtraInfo.p_key = Master.fk_ExtraInfo
WHERE  
    (fk_key=:Fk)
```

And recordset is empty but **without `CASE`** statement recordset has data.
(I can't use a calculated column or SQL Server view because I have use dynamic query)

Comment: Does the Sql work correctly when executed from Sql Server Management Studio (or Query Analyzer, if it's an older server version)? Case statements usually work fine via Ado datasets in Delphi..

Comment: @MartynA, Yes, it does work fine in SQL Server and returned recordset

Comment: Then I belive you'll have to make a View.

Comment: I have seen this behaviour before with "complex" sql. Try to refactor you select statement to use an Common Table Expression.

Or an temporary table.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt, I cant make View  because part of the query/fields is dynamically generated.

Comment: What table does the fk_key column belong to that's referred to in the main Where clause at the end of your query?

Comment: @MartynA, , This SQL-Command in SQL-Server Management Studio does work fine but in Delphi in the same state does not work.

Comment: Sure, but I was asking about fk_key to see if I could replicate the problem here.  It might help if you add the DDL for your three tables to the q.

Comment: Switch to TADOConnection + TADOQuery?

Comment: @JanDoggen, TADOConnection + TADOQuery does not work!

Comment: @Mohamad have you tried CTE og at temporary table?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt, No, I solve the problem by convert Case block to View and Left joined it meanwhile I have test this SQL statement with FireDAC component and it worked. In my opinion, Select statement in Case in ADO  components does not work.

Comment: The whole case expression is kind of off anyway. You have top 1 but no order by. Also, it seems like you are using this subselect as a way of doing an exists check. A left join would be more appropriate and performant here.

Comment: Actually, CASE works just fine with ADO. maybe the parameter is the problem/bug.

Comment: @kobik, As I wrote earlier, By one value for parameter with case the ADODataSet returned no recordset and by same value without case the ADODataSet has recordset!

Comment: @SeanLange, Note that, This query with same parameter value does work fine in SSMS.

Comment: What I mean is, try this command with `TADODataSet.ParamCheck := False` and dont use `:Fk` as parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Select section in CASE statement to below :

```
    CASE
       ( SELECT TOP (1) personeli_State 
         FROM Detail 
          WHERE Detail.personeli_State = 'Test' 
           AND Detail.sended = 0
           AND Detail.FK_Key = Master.pk_key )
```

In my opinion, it seems that ADO changes the priority of the execution plan...!